# Cant change values in text box with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am trying to take numbers entered by a user and use them for calculating values, and then having these numbers displayed in the text boxes. When I submit the values, The text boxes to the right do not change. Any Ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Car Payment Calculator</title>
<style>
  html, body { 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
  } 

  #pagewidth { 
    max-width:9000em;  
    min-width:1000em;  
  }

  #header {
    position:relative; 
    height:150px; 
    background-color:#06F9FC; 
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    overflow:auto;
  } 

  #maincol {
    background-color: #FCC66C;  
    position: relative; 
  }
</style>
    <HTA:APPLICATION ID="myCarPayment"
    APPLICATIONNAME="Car Payment Calculator"
    SYSMENU="yes"
    BORDER="thin"
    BORDERSTYLE="normal"
    CAPTION="yes"
    ICON=""
    MAXIMIZEBUTTON="yes"
    MINIMIZEBUTTON="yes"
    SHOWINTASKBAR="yes"
    SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
    SCROLL="no"
    VERSION="1.0"
    WINDOWSTATE="normal"/>

  <script>
    window.resizeTo(300,300);

    function calculate() {
      var years= document.forms.myForm.years.value;  
      var monthly= amount/(years*12);  
      var number= monthly/amount;  
      var form = document.forms.myForm;  
      var loanAmount = form.loanAmount.value;  
      var downPayment = '0';  
      var anualInterestRate = form.interestRate.value;  
      var years = form.years.value;  
      var monthRate = anualInterestRate/12;  
      var numberOfPayments = years * 12;  
      var Principal=loanAmount-downPayement;  
      var valueNumber = document.getElementById("numPay");  
      var vlaueMonthly = document.getElementById("monthlyPay");  

      valueNumber.value = numberOfPayments;  
      valueMonthly.value = monthly;
    }  

  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <pre>
            <p>This application will help you calculate car payments.<br/>
Just enter the information and hit Calculate!</p>
        </pre>
    </div>
    <div id="maincol">
        <pre>
            <form name="myForm" action="" onsubmit="calculate()">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Loan Amount:</td><td> <input type="number" name="loanAmount"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Interest Rate:</td><td> <input type="number" name="interestRate"></td><td>Number of Payments:</td><td><input type="text" name="numberPayments" id="numPay" value="0"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Number of Years:</td><td> <input type="number" name="years"></td><td>Monthly Payment:</td><td><input type="text" name="monthlyPayments" id="monthlyPay" value="0"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Calculate"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </pre>
    </div>
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: `ReferenceError: amount is not defined`, you've used `amount`, but never defined it - `var monthly= amount/(years*12);`. When writing `Javascript` it's always best practise to use a debugger, like `Firebug` or `Chrome developer tools`, and look at the `console`.

Comment: Thank you. I was unaware that there were debuggers for this sort of thing. I am trying to teach myself in an independent study.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an error in your callback function `calculate()`:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: amount is not defined
```

You're using `amount` but you've not defined/declared it.

I'm not sure what the value of `amount` should be.

Comment: And there's a typo `downPayement` vs `downPayment`. And a typo on `vlaueMonthly` - `ReferenceError: valueMonthly is not defined`

Comment: I didn't check beyond that, there are likely more errors. `calculate()` should probably `return false` since the form should not be submitted (I think?). `event.preventDefault()` would get rid of a lot of nonsense here.

Comment: Yep true, it shouldn't actually `submit` anything ie making a POST request, I changed the submit to `<a onclick="calculate(); return false" href="#">Calc</a>`

Comment: The value that is assigned to amount should not matter since it is later reassigned in the function calculate(), correct? although I should have been more proactive when checking spelling.

Answer (score 0):

Also get the value from input and convert it into number by using `parsetInt()`, you need convert them into number before calculation.

```
  var years =   parseInt(document.forms.myForm.years.value, 10);
  var loanAmount = parseInt(form.loanAmount.value, 10);  
  var valueNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById("numPay"), 10);  
  var vlaueMonthly = parseInt(document.getElementById("monthlyPay"), 10);
```